# How does 3rd level Jump work on the caster?

Tags: spells, actions, pathfinder-2e

As a 1st level spell, [Jump](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=167) enables you cast *and* jump in just one action.

When heightened to 3rd level, and cast on *someone else*, the target obviously needs a separate to actually move.

When the caster targets himself with the heightened version, can he still jump with the action used for casting?

Comment: I don't know if I'd say that the non-self target needs to spend an extra action to move, as opposed to getting an immediate jump. I'm not really sure how it is supposed to be read myself, but I've sorta arbitrarily chosen that the caster gets a free instant-jump in my game, and I haven't really found it overpowered at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, any target* of the Jump spell may immediately jump 30ft. Targets of the 3rd level Jump spell can then repeat the effect using the Leap Action.

From [Heightened Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=273):

> In addition, many spells have additional specific benefits when they are heightened, such as increased damage. These extra benefits are described at the end of the spell’s stat block. Some heightened entries specify one or more levels at which the spell must be prepared or cast to gain these extra advantages. **Each of these heightened entries states specifically which aspects of the spell change at the given level.**

The Jump spell reads

> Your legs surge with strength, ready to leap high and far. You jump 30 feet in any direction without touching the ground. You must land on a space of solid ground within 30 feet of you, or else you fall after using your next action.
>
> **Heightened (3rd)** The range becomes touch, the target changes to one touched creature, and the duration becomes 1 minute, allowing the target to jump as described whenever it takes the Leap action.

The Heightened entry doesn't include "instead" or any such language, so the modifications to targeting and duration do not alter the base benefit of the spell. Deciding that there is no initial benefit is probably a reasonable table decision, but in such a case I would recommend that it applies equally to the caster themselves and other targets they may pick.

---

*Technically, an overly strict RAW is that the spellcaster gains the one-time benefit of Jump while the target gains the continuous effect. I don't think this makes any sense and should fall under making a ruling that *seems* correct over the literal meaning of the words.

Comment: The target of the heightened version is "one touched creature". If you touch another creature, the caster gets no benefit at all from the spell.

Comment: Obviously, except the rest of the spell is phrased like it can only target you, so common sense has to be applied.